Solid bounded by five planes
Consider the solid limited by the three coordinates planes and the planes $x+y=1$ and $x+z = 1$. How can I set the limits so I can integrate in this region?
Ideas: the origin is include so $0\leq x, y, z$. Regarding the upper bounds, I can set
$0\leq x \leq 1$, then $0\leq y \leq 1-x$. I need the upper bound for $z$. I am not sure if I should set $0\leq z \leq y$, because of the plane $z = 1-x$ and $y = 1-x$. If this is correct, why
$$0\leq z \leq y$$ instead of
$$
0\leq z \leq 1-x?
$$

$(0,0,1)$ lies on the boundary of the region, so ....

@Japp I draw it again putting concrete points of the planes. I think $0\leq y\leq1, 1-y\leq x\leq 1, 0\leq z\leq 1-x$

Your new $x$ range is on the wrong side of the $x+y=1$ boundary plane. It can help to change the equations of the boundary planes of the region into inequalities to more precisely define what the region is because an inequality tells you on which side of a plane it lies. You should find that the region is enclosed by $x\ge 0$, $y\ge0$, $z\ge0$, $x+y\le1$, $x+z\le1$. This forms a square pyramid with the vertices $(0,0,0)$,$(0,1,0)$,$(0,0,1)$,$(0,1,1)$ and $(1,0,0)$. The following set of ranges in your question were correct $0\le x\le1$, $0\le y\le1-x$, $0\le z\le1-x$, but not $z\le y$.

If you want to do $y$ first, then $0\le y\le1$, $0\le x\le1-y$, $0\le z\le1-x$ works.
